# Appcelerator Titanium Studio: Usage of jQuery

Tags: jquery, titanium, appcelerator

I'm using Appcelerator Titanium Studio to build my App. I need jQuery in there (yes, I know, DOM does not work).
Anyway I found this: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/JavaScript+Library+Support#JavaScriptLibrarySupport-jQuery%28http://jquery.org%29

I did all the steps in there but I still get an error if I'm using "jQuery" or "$":

> Can't find variable: jQuery

Why doesn't this work? How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you need jQuery for [if not for DOM manipulation](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/121/use-of-jquery).... Why not just use pure JavaScript libraries (that derive from jQuery in spirit) like underscore.

Answer (score -2):

A thorough read of the documention you specified would let you know that you are confused by the topic. The link you provided talks about using jQuery in Titanium Studio, it says nothing about using jQuery with Appcelerator Titanium for building mobile apps.